# How to solve incorrect Indentation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, indentation

Hello is there any way to solve this recurrent problem of incorrect indentation in Haskell ? I am using VSCode and many times i just have to put an extra space to be able to compile the module.Is there any way (extension) which can show me how to manage tabs/spaces...etc ?

```
module DB where
        import Company
        let db= [
                Company{
                    compName="Siemens",
                    year=1912,
                    employees=[
                        Employee{age=25,name="Stew",job=Worker},
                        Employee{age=25,name="Michael",job=Manager,wage=66},
                        Employee{age=22,name="Stew",job=Worker,wage=33.0},
                        Employee{age=32,name="Dew",job=Unemployed,wage=0.5},
                        Employee{age=44,name="Drey",job=Worker,wage=30.0}]
                },
                Company{
                    compName="ABB",
                    year=1925,
                    employees=[
                        Employee{age=18,name="Michael",job=Manager,wage=21},
                        Employee{age=23,name="Rey",job=Worker,wage=18.5},
                        Employee{age=55,name="Barry",job=Unemployed,wage=0.7},
                        Employee{age=64,name="Dean",job=Worker,wage=30.0}]
                },
                Company{
                     compName="EATON",
                     year=1977,
                     employees=[
                        Employee{age=18,name="Raynald",job=Manager,wage=21},
                        Employee{age=23,name="Fitz",job=Worker,wage=18.5},
                        Employee{age=55,name="Alex",job=Worker,wage=0.7},
                        Employee{age=34,name="Bob",job=Worker,wage=23.0},
                        Employee{age=33,name="Odo",job=Unemployed,wage=24.0}]
                      }
             ]
```

Comment: **1.** Never use tabs, ever. **2.** Use indentation to group stuff together that belongs together. **3.** Don't indent top-level stuff like `import` and global definitions. (Also don't use `let` for these, that's only needed for _local_ definitions.)

Comment: Modern GHC should already warn about tabs. You should avoid them, or be quite disciplined in how tabs are used. Also note that indentation matters only after `let, do, where, case of`. Inside `[ ]` there are no rules. Ensure the last `]` above is indented more than the `db` after `let`. (And `let` is also wrong there...)

Comment: Oh it was actually because `let`.I thought you can use it ouside a method.I am sorry for the goose hunt.It can be closed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using the `let` keyword outside a method.